# Integrating firebase analytics into ionic2 application

Tags: cordova, firebase, google-analytics, ionic2, firebase-analytics

Ive been creating a ionic2 application that uses cordova-plugin-firebase for use in firebase analytics.

Im using the following functions in my ionPageLoaded()

Track Page Views

```
 window.FirebasePlugin.logEvent("page_view", {page: "Event List"});
```

Track Action

```
   window.FirebasePlugin.logEvent("volunteer_action", {action: "donate"});`
```

However, my analytics are not being updated in firebase, i.e my analytics tab is empty.

How do I make sure that page views and actions are tracked in Firebase Analytics?

Link to the plugin 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase

Comment: Hi, did you get it working? Thanks :)

Comment: No not yet, any help would be great :D

Comment: Any update on this - Can you use Firebase analytics and Ionic?